# How to improve my Wordpress filter to include empty custom fields

Tags: php

I have a custom columns of suppliers and I want to create a filter in which I could filter my products based on empty fields as well. I have the following:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'my_theme_posts_filter' );

function my_theme_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow;
    $type = 'product';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'product' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['Supplier']) && $_GET['Supplier'] != '') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = '_select';
        $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $_GET['Supplier'];
    }
}
```

If I place '' in my dropdown list nothing happens of course